# When to properly use Present Progressive statements?

Tags: sentence-usage

Can present progressive statements be use at present or for the future? or both?

Answer (score 4):

The basic meaning of present progressive is 'present'. If I say 'I'm having dinner with my parents', I mean 'now'. I can always add 'now', but I don't have to.

Present progressive can also be used for the future, but only if I state some future time, or if some future time is understood in the context. I can say 'I'm having dinner with my parents tomorrow', or if you ask me 'What are you doing tomorrow?', I can answer 'I'm having dinner with my parents'.

'Future' can turn into 'present' very quickly. If we are sitting at our office desks, I can say 'I'm going home soon'. Then, while standing up, I can say 'I'm going home now'. Then, while walking out the door, I can say 'I'm going home'. (In real life I would not say all three of those things!)

Comment: What would you say if it's a real life?