# Reference Time and Event Time in the Pr. Progressive tense

Tags: grammar, tense

I've read the [tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/tense/info) wiki summary and I would like to understand how it works on practice. Consider the Present Progressive Tense construction, denoting fixed arrangements:

> I'm getting a new job the next month.

We're talking about the future, such that `ST<RT=ET`. So why we use Pr.Prog instead of Future tense with something aspect?

Comment: The basic idea is that it's so certain that it feels real to the speaker, so real that the speaker can think of it as something that is happening.

Comment: This answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/27433/2818) might answer your question.