# present progressive indicating the future

Tags: present-continuous, future-time

Can the present progressive be used to indicate the future as follows?

> John is working at the store for two months.

If so, how does it differ from "John is going to work at the store for two months"?

Comment: You can google this.

Comment: *John is working at the store for two months* could feasibly be said ***before he starts that two weeks of employment***, but the "default" reading would be that he's already started doing it. On the other hand, *John is going to work at the store for two months* would normally be taken to imply he ***hasn't*** yet started doing so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to properly use Present Progressive statements?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27431/when-to-properly-use-present-progressive-statements)