# Present Progressive indicates progressive or near future?

Tags: present-continuous

A woman says, “My toes are turning red. I think I’m getting frostbite.” at 0:46 of the ABC News clip: https://ia600909.us.archive.org/29/items/KGO_20101216_013000_ABC_World_News_With_Diane_Sawyer/KGO_20101216_013000_ABC_World_News_With_Diane_Sawyer.mp4?start=1620&end=1680&ignore=x.mp4

To my knowledge, Present Progressive can also indicate near future. So, I was wondering which "I think I’m getting frostbite." means: she is in the process of developing frostbite now, or she is not developing frostbite at this time but will be getting frostbite soon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to properly use Present Progressive statements?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27431/when-to-properly-use-present-progressive-statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She means "I am starting to develop frostbite".

It's quite common to say "I think I'm getting a cold" when we feel the first symptoms. We don't mean "I plan to get one in the near future"!